# How to set multiple cookies to a website using pypeteer in python

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, pyppeteer

I'm trying to take a screenshot using pyppeteer(python module) it works fine . But for some cases, we need to set cookies to access the given URL.

**code:**

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
import base64
async def main(target):
    browser = await launch(headless=True)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({ 'width': 1600, 'height': 800 });
    cookie =[{'name': 'wordpress_test_cookie', 'value': 'WP+Cookie+check', 'url': 'http://www.testwordpress.com/'}, {'name': ' wp-settings-time-1', 'value': '1577779484', 'url': 'http://www.testwordpress.com/'}]
    await page.setCookie(cookie);
    await page.goto(target)
    await page.screenshot({'path': '/tmp/screen.png', 'fullPage': True})
    await browser.close()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main(sys.argv[1]))
```

How to pass multiple cookies to a website using pyppeteer?

**Note:** Its working properly for a single cookie (JSON object).The problem comes only when the cookies are array of objects

**Environment :**

OS : ubuntu18.04

pyppeteer version :  0.0.25

language: python3.6